# Require config: get `paths` object from JSON in Gruntfile.js and main.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I've recently run into several irritating cases where our Require configuration's `paths` object falls out of sync between its Grunt instantiation in `requirejs.dist.options.paths` and our front-end bootstrap (`main.js`) in the `paths` property passed to `require.config( paths: { /* etc */ } } )`.

In an effort to avoid grunt work, I thought to save the `paths` as a JSON object in the file `require_config_paths.json`.

I get hold of the JSON in `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```
requirejs: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      paths: grunt.file.readJSON( '/assets/js/src/require_config_paths.json' )
    }
  }
};
```

What to do in `main.js` is the pancake. I've currently ended up with the following:

```
// Temporary config to circumvent error when I Require the JSON later on:
// Cannot optimize network URL, skipping: require_config_paths.json?define
require.config( {
  paths: {
    'require_config_paths.json?define' : 'empty:'
  }
} );

// Require the JSON: handle as JSONP via define callback and pass as `paths`
require( [ 'require_config_paths.json?define' ], function configureR( paths ){
  require.config( {
    paths: paths
  } );
} );
```

But the attempt at setting `empty:` doesn't do anything – it still gets skipped because network URLs can't be optimized – which is an odd complaint, seeing as the resource is implicitly a local one.

Answer (score 0):

`empty:` is something you want to put only in the build config you pass to `r.js`. You don't put it in your HTML or in files loaded by your HTML.

In your case this would mean putting the `empty:` setting for `'require_config_paths.json?define'` inside `'/assets/js/src/require_config_paths.json'`. I realize that it will be loaded at runtime and will then override the setting for `'require_config_paths.json?define'` with `empty:` but by that time it should not matter.

Comment: That's true – this code then effectively becomes `r.js`-specific, which it shouldn't be. I should probably take that code out, since it doesn't actually solve the problem anyway.